# CoreData - Save/Load functionality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, load, save

I need to add functionality to my iPad app so that I can save and load notes from a `UITextView` then load them when the user selects the date in the `UIDatePicker` that it was originally saved on, much like a calendar, notes for different dates.

I have asked around on Stack Overflow and people have been spoon feeding me code samples but I am not quite latching on. I really want to learn how to do this, however currently its fairly important that I get the functionality added in.

Here is where I asked:

- [Core Data iPhone - Save/Load depending on Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133405/core-data-iphone-save-load-depending-on-date)
- [Save and Load Data - CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177398/save-and-load-data-coredata)

Comment: have you got core data set up properly? Its a bitch to get used to setting up, but just having the sqlite file won't be enough.

Comment: Well thats the thing, Im not sure where Im going right or wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save and Load Data - CoreData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177398/save-and-load-data-coredata)

Comment: Since this is not a new question I'm voting to close

Comment: I'll try again to close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:

[Core Data iPhone - Save/Load depending on Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133405/core-data-iphone-save-load-depending-on-date)

[Save and Load Data - CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177398/save-and-load-data-coredata)